# Some FTP clients timing out on data connection to Pure-FTPd

Tags: ftp, pure-ftpd

I'm trying to connect to a server via FTP and I'm having some problems.
Server is a CentOS with Pure-FTPd.

My usual client is `lftp` which on this server gets stuck at "Making data connection". All google results about this suggest setting `ftp:ssl-allow no` but that didn't help in my case.

I also tried other clients and experienced the same behavior with `ncftp` and the graphical gnome `gftp`: connection is made but no data is transferred even for a simple `ls`.

However, connection and data transfer work with basic `ftp` client and from a Perl script using Net::FTP module.

Any suggestion on what options I can try to get the other clients working?

Answer (score 3):

Try using ftp in passive mode
the relevant setting in lftp is `ftp:passive-mode`

Comment: Nope, didn't work

Comment: try using a sniffer and see if you get some kind of error, or what is the difference between the successful clients and lftp.

Comment: Try /disabling/ passive mode `set ftp:passive-mode off`. I've had more trouble with it on than off lately.

Comment: Not related to the actual problem, but whenever you have the choice, default to sftp rather than straight ftp. Doesn't suffer from the active/passive crap, works anywhere you can make an SSH connection to, and secure data transmission to boot.

Comment: passive mode on or off seems to make no difference, and unfortunately I have no ssh access

Answer (score 2):

It may be the problem with ssl. Try:

```
lftp -e 'set ftp:ssl-allow no' ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the ssl option or the passive-mode option didn't work, but the combination of both options worked:

```
lftp -e 'set ftp:ssl-allow off && set ftp:passive-mode off' ...
```